# Perl or MySQL for accessing and retrieving information

Tags: html, mysql, perl, parsing

I'm trying to retrieve a couple of webpages so that I can manipulate their information. I am looking for what are the best tools and packages for doing this. Preferably, I would appreciate to use **Perl** for parsing the tables, but I would be fine with using **MySQL** too, though I would have to learn it. 
(I believe they are HTML tables, despite the page being coded in Java?).

I am not asking for any code, but for your opinion, tips and suggestions on how I can accomplish this. My intentions are, for now, to just parse the tables, merge them, and build a single table that has the information from both sites in different columns. This general table would only need to be updated once a day at most.

The tables can be found [in here, please scroll down](http://scrap.tf/items) and [in here, the full table](http://backpack.tf/pricelist/spreadsheet).

Thank you in advance for all the help!

Comment: You are parsing web pages so how does MySql come into the picture. Besides you are asking for an opinion

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Ok, I'm very sorry. I'll delete my question in 5 minutes. I'm sorry

Comment: Given that there was an answer, is it still ok if I delete the question? I don't want that to be rude or unfair for the person who answered..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For web page retrieve, you can use the Web::Scraper, HTML::DOM, and also the LWP related modules.
And for SQL, the DBI module is very powerful. You can search these using the cpan.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be how to do webscraping. I don't see how MySQL would come into play with this. For webscrapint I suggest that you look at the CPAN modules [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) and [HTML::TableExtractor](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aTableExtractor)

Comment: You could also look at using WWW::Mechanize::Cached before going into production with your code. It can greatly speed up testing etc.

Comment: Thanks! These kind of answers were exactly what I was looking for with this thread, though I know it's somewhat out of what is usually asked on SE.